# Tower Defence game help in as3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cs4

I have been working off of a tutorial of a tower defence game(http://www.guahanweb.com/2009/01/31/tower-defense-in-as3-part-iv/) but I have been having trouble with making a second map/road. I've gotten to be able to change the road. (If you haven't figured out from the source file that he gives its the this.points =[[*_*_]] in the MagicTD file) I have replaced

```
this.points = [[2, -1], [2, 5], [6, 5], [6, 16], [28, 16], [28, 4], [12, 4], [12, 19], [22, 19], [22, 12], [36, 12]];
            this.grid_size = 16;

            // this.setupTarget();
            this.drawBackground();
            this.setupMap();
            this.setupTimers();
            this.setupListeners();
```

with

```
map1btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, clickmp1);



            this.grid_size=16;
```

and (map1btn is a button) and clickmp1 is

```
public function clickmp1(event:MouseEvent) {
            this.points=[[1,-1],[2,5],[6,5],[6,16],[28,16],[28,4],[12,4],[12,19],[22,19],[22,12],[36,12]];
this.setupTimers();
            this.drawBackground();

            this.setupMap();
            this.setListeners();



        }
```

(check the source file for the rest (http://code.guahanweb.com/viewsource/td04/))

whats happening is the enemy is going under the map and the grid.

thanks

thor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you need to set your map back behind everything. To do that you'd do something like:

```
this.setChildIndex(yourMapInstanceName, 0);
```

[Docs for MovieClip.setChildIndex()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/DisplayObjectContainer.html#setChildIndex%28%29)

This assumes everything involved has "`this`" as a common parent.

Alternatively, to throw something on top of everything:

```
this.setChildIndex(yourMapInstanceName, this.numChildren - 1);
```

Comment: thanks worked perfectly. just did this.setChildIndex(this.backgroundMC,  0); for the background and this.setChildIndex(this.map, 1); for the road